# How to retrieve specific value from String in java

Tags: java, string

I have a String field which contains value :

```
 String a = "Local/5028@from-queue-bd7f,1";
```

Now As per my need i need value '5028' extracted from the above String field.

Comment: Have you tried anything? RegExp's for instance?

Comment: Does the value always start at the same position or is it always between `/` and `@` or is it even a totally different rule?

Comment: Sir i tried to do it with Splitting the String value

Comment: The [Oracle Java Regex Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) will guide you through the whole thing.

Comment: Do you know regular expressions? Seems to be your friend in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This splits the string on each `/` *and* `@`.

```
String a = "Local/5028@from-queue-bd7f,1";
System.out.println(a.split("[/@]")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#substring` function to retrieve the value. You need to pass beginning and ending index as a parameter.

```
String a = "Local/5028@from-queue-bd7f,1";
System.out.println(a.substring(a.indexOf('/')+1, a.indexOf('@')));
```

Comment: -1 for allowing magic number and not really a generic solution. Also it is an error prone solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your format is consistent then you can either use substring method or you can split the string using / and @, and then take the second value from the tokens array.

Answer (score 0):

If this string is always in the given format then you can try this :

```
String temp=a.split("@")[0];
System.out.println(temp.substring(temp.length()-4,temp.length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using REGEX:**

```
 String a = "Local/5028@from-queue-bd7f,1";
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
         Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
         System.out.println(m.find() + " " + m.group());
```

**Using String.Split:**

```
String a = "Local/5028@from-queue-bd7f,1";
         String[] split = a.split("/");
         System.out.println(split[1].split("@")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your string format is fixed, you can use:

```
String a = "Local/5028@from-queue-bd7f,1";
a = a.substring(a.indexOf('/') + 1, a.indexOf('@'));
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Sir i have one more case String a = "Local/5028-from-queue-bd7f,1"; PLz tell me how to combine this condition in the code

Comment: again if your string is kind of fixed, try `a.substring(a.indexOf('/') + 1, a.indexOf("from") - 1)` to handle both